# Return Subscription from Service - but how to use async result also in Service?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-httpclient

Sorry for the bad title, I really didn't have a good idea how to phrase it.

Let's assume I have a service call somewhere in an Angular component like:

```
this.myService.postObject(object).subscribe((serverData) => {
  console.log('Server Name:' + serverData.name)
});
```

This works perfectly of course when the MyService looks like:

```
postObject(dataObject: MyObject) {
  return this.http.post(`http://server/object`, dataObject);
}
```

But what when I want to react on the async result not only individually in only subscriptions but additionally generally for all calls - so ideally like this:

```
postObject(dataObject: MyObject) {
  return this.http.post(`http://server/object`, dataObject)
    .subscribe(
      (serverData) => {
        console.log('Server Name:' + serverData.name)
      })
}
```

> This of course doesn't work as I can't return the .subscribe and then .subscribe again to it.

But I think of logging, messaging and other general activities which need to be done when the post was executed.

Is there a way to achieve this or am I just blind to see? :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what [tap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/do.html) is for, tap is not going to modify your returning observable but can take care of things like logging. If you want to modify the returned Obsertvable, use [map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html) instead

```
postObject(dataObject: MyObject) {
  return this.http.post(`http://server/object`, dataObject)
    .pipe(tap(serverData => {
        console.log('Server Name:' + serverData.name)
      }))
}
```

> The RxJS tap operator (as in "wiretap") lets the code inspect good and error values passing through the observable without disturbing them.

https://angular.io/guide/http